# How to remove "provided by ..." label on Google Maps app

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent

[image]

Hi,

I opened with an Intent the Google Maps app to a specific location.
Is it possible to remove the label on the bottom left **provided by** (in the red circle on the screenshot)?

I use this method on Android to open Google Maps to a specific location:

```
    /**
 * Open Google Maps to specific coordinates and show the name of the place with the label
 * @param context   the {@link Context}
 * @param latitude  the latitude
 * @param longitude the longitude
 * @param label     the name of the place
 */
public static void openGoogleMaps(Context context, double latitude, double longitude, String label) {
    String uriBegin = "geo:" + latitude + "," + longitude;
    String query = latitude + "," + longitude + "(" + label + ")";
    String encodedQuery = Uri.encode(query);
    String uriString = uriBegin + "?q=" + encodedQuery + "&z=16";
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriString);
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to slightly change your query. Right now your uri is

```
geo:lat,lng?q=lat,lng(label)
```

Change that to

```
geo:lat,lng?q=label
```

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intents) is not very clear about when the `provided by` info is added. Possibly when you add your own label through parenthesis.

The trick here is to avoid adding your own label, but instead use that as a search query. Depending on what you use as a label, Google should be smart enough to find that place anyway, and display a localized label.